# Set MUIDataTable theme header position to 'sticky'

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I'm trying to set the position of my thead to be 'sticky' in MUIDataTable .

I have a `getMuiTheme` method:

```
export const getMuiTheme = () => createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
      MuiTableCell: {
          head: {
              backgroundColor: "#c1e1ec !important",
              position: 'sticky',
          }
      },
  }
});
```

And I set this theme in my `MuiThemeProvider`:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>                                                    
   <MUIDataTable
      title={renderTitle()}
      data={showUnits()}
      columns={columns}
      options={options}
   />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

The `backgroundColor` works, but my position do not work. If I manually change the `thead` position using the browser console, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your table a **height**, and then only it will work. For example put `tableBodyHeight: '400px'` in your **MUIDataTable options**

```
const options = {
    tableBodyHeight: "400px"
  };
```

To see more details please visit [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-joliot-np9czi?file=/src/App.js:5676-5890) example.

Besides, you can also have a look at the link below to see the issue & solution visually: [TestWise Replay | Stack Overflow QA - MUI data-table header sticky](https://dashboard.testwise.io/replays/eJIcMRZBfNr)